# Finding data immediately before a particular time in xts objects in R

Tags: r, time, xts

I have two `xts` datasets, the order book and the market data, and they are similar to the following:

Order Book:

```
Time                 |      Price
-------------------------------------
2017-01-02 10:00:02  |      5.00
2017-01-02 10:00:05  |      6.00
2017-01-02 10:00:13  |      5.00
2017-01-02 10:00:16  |      4.00
2017-01-02 10:00:24  |      2.00
```

Market Data:

```
Time                 |      Ask Price
---------------------------------------
2017-01-02 10:00:01  |      4.00
2017-01-02 10:00:02  |      3.00
2017-01-02 10:00:27  |      1.00
2017-01-02 10:00:56  |      2.00
2017-01-02 10:00:57  |      1.00
```

Now, for each observation in the order book I would like to find the market data observation stictly before the time of the order in the order book. For example, from the two datasets above, if I look at observation 3 in the order book then the Market Data strictly before this is at index 2 (i.e. at time `10:00:05`) of the Market Data.

Now, there are only two conditions I have to follow - firstly, as I mentioned before, the market data observation must be strictly before the order book observation. The second condition is that both the observations must have occurred on the same day. I've actually written two different functions to try and perform this task but both give different results, so I'm pretty sure I'm wrong. If someone could help me out a bit with this then I'd really appreciate it! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
require(data.table)
require(lubridate)
################
# Recreate data
#################
s<-
    "2017-01-02 10:00:02 5.00
    2017-01-02 10:00:05 6.00
    2017-01-02 10:00:13 5.00
    2017-02-02 10:00:16 4.00
    2017-02-02 10:00:24 2.00"
# note I changed the date in last two lines to answer your question
s1 <-
    "2017-01-02 10:00:01 4.00
    2017-01-02 10:00:02 3.00
    2017-01-02 10:00:27 1.00
    2017-01-02 10:00:56 2.00
    2017-01-02 10:00:57 1.00"
# I'm reading from delimiter, day and minutes come in two separates columns
O <- read.delim(textConnection(s),header=FALSE,sep=" ",strip.white=TRUE)
M <- read.delim(textConnection(s1),header=FALSE,sep=" ",strip.white=TRUE)
setDT(O);setDT(M)
setnames(O,c("time","m","price"));setnames(M,c("time","m","ask_price"))
O[,time:=paste(time,m)];M[,time:=paste(time,m)] # paste hours and minutes
O[,m:=NULL];M[,m:=NULL] # remove minutes
O[,time:= lubridate::ymd_hms(time)];M[,time:= lubridate::ymd_hms(time)]# extract time

################
# Analysis
#################
setkey(O,time); setkey(M,time)
# this will identify all orders (O) after Market sessions (M)
M[O, roll = T]
#time ask_price price
#1: 2017-01-02 10:00:02         3     5
#2: 2017-01-02 10:00:05         3     6
#3: 2017-01-02 10:00:13         3     5
#4: 2017-02-02 10:00:16         1     4
#5: 2017-02-02 10:00:24         1     2

# this will identify all orders (O) after market session (M) 
# within a time span of 24 hours
twenty_four_hours<-60*60*24 
res<-M[O, roll = twenty_four_hours]
#time ask_price price
#1: 2017-01-02 10:00:02         3     5
#2: 2017-01-02 10:00:05         3     6
#3: 2017-01-02 10:00:13         3     5
#4: 2017-02-02 10:00:16        NA     4
#5: 2017-02-02 10:00:24        NA     2
res[!is.na(ask_price),] # now we remove lines without values
# time ask_price price
#1: 2017-01-02 10:00:02         3     5
#2: 2017-01-02 10:00:05         3     6
#3: 2017-01-02 10:00:13         3     5
```